# CRM 2011 Custom Report rsProcessAborted System.TimeoutException

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, timeoutexception

I am having a problem with a Custom Report in CRM 2011.

I am creating a FetchXML based report in BIDS, where the preview works with no problems. I then upload the RDL file into CRM.

When I run the report I get an rsProcessingAborted Error (not much info here). I tried running the same report through Reports server page. Here at least I get a somwhat detailed Exception message:

> Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: An unexpected error occurred. System.TimeoutException: This request operation sent to
>   net.tcp://scrmq01/CrmSandboxSdkListener-w3wp did not receive a reply
>   within the configured timeout (00:02:00). The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. This may be
>   because the service is still processing the operation or because the
>   service was unable to send a reply message. Please consider increasing
>   the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel
>   and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service
>   is able to connect to the client.
>
> An unexpected error occurred. This request operation sent to net.tcp://scrmq01/CrmSandboxSdkListener-w3wp did not receive a reply
>   within the configured timeout (00:02:00). The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. This may be
>   because the service is still processing the operation or because the
>   service was unable to send a reply message. Please consider increasing
>   the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel
>   and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service
>   is able to connect to the client.

The report works flawlessly on CRM if I set a Filter. Say, only data of the past 7 days.

So it seems that the amount of data my report is returning is causing a timeout. I have changed the Timeout settings on the Reports web  page to "No timeout" as well as increased the OLEDBTimeout registery key to a larger value, all to no avail.

Does anyone know where this CrmSandboxSdkListener timeout can be changed.

Comment: Can you increase the timeout period or increase the performance of report sql by adding index. reduce the report data!

Comment: I have no idea where to increase the CrmSandboxSdkListener timeout. Its not an SQL Report but rather a FetchXML report through CRM 2011, so tampering with the DB is not an option.